# What do we call the disjuncts of the conclusion of an argument?

Tags: logic, terminology

If we have an argument with a single premise of the form $A \wedge B$, then we can refer to $A$ and $B$ collectively as "premises" of the argument without causing any confusion. However if we have an argument with a conclusion of the form $A \vee B$, then I wouldn't feel comfortable calling $A$ and $B$ "conclusions," since we don't get to conclude *both.* So if not "conclusions," then what do we call the disjuncts of the conclusion of an argument?

Along a similar vein, if we have a sequent of the form

$$\varphi_0,\ldots,\varphi_{n-1} \vdash \psi_0,\ldots,\psi_{n-1}$$

then I think it would be appropriate to call the $\varphi$'s *premises*. But what can we call the $\psi$'s?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a conclusion $\psi = A \lor B$, then $A$, $B$ can each be called a disjunct of the conclusion $\psi$.

If you mean by $$\varphi_0,\ldots,\varphi_{n-1} \vdash \psi_0,\ldots,\psi_{n-1}$$ to be taken as $$\varphi_0,\ldots,\varphi_{n-1} \vdash \psi_0 \lor \ldots \lor\psi_{n-1}$$

then the $\psi_i$ are each disjunctions of the conclusion, where the conclusion (the entire disjunction) is what's implied by the conjunction of the $\varphi_i$.  The only thing we are licenced to say in this case is that *at least one* (perhaps only one?) of the $\psi_i$ must be implied by the conjunction of the $\varphi_i$.

Comment: Well that's not very useful. Imagine if every time you wanted to say "premise," you had to say "conjunct of the antecedent."

Comment: The fact is you cannot isolate and make any statements about a disjunct $A$ apart from the fact that it is a "candidate": it may or may not be implied by the antecedent. (Since any other disjunct in a conclusion that's a disjunction may be the sole entity that holds. Recall: if $$\varphi_0,\ldots,\varphi_{n-1} \vdash \psi_0$$ then $$\varphi_0,\ldots,\varphi_{n-1} \vdash \psi_0 \lor \psi_1 \lor \ldots \lor \psi_{n-1}$$